# Reviewing direct changes in Production

Tags: deployment, debugging, unit-test

We are experiencing errors in a class in Production. They must be due to changes which were done directly into Production since nothing has changed in the code and we were able to deploy things just two weeks ago. Since the class is in Production we are unable to deploy anything or even deactivate the class which is producing the error.

Does anybody know a method by which I could see EVERY change which has occurred in Production recently (maybe 2 weeks) ? I know we could manually go into things (fields,validation rules, workflows etc) and just see what has been modified, but that is quite a task. I would love a way to be able to get a list of EVERY component with a Last Modified date next to it - or something to that effect.

Is there a report which I could run to get this information ? Is there an Eclipse method ? Is there an app which could help with this ?

One other question : Does anybody know a back-door method to deactivate an error-ing class in Production ? I've attempted changing the XML file to "Inactive" in a sandbox in Eclipse and then deploying to Production but that's not working due to the errors. I'm wondering if there is any kind of (undocumented) method.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code changes cannot be made directly into Production, they have to be deployed and during the deployment all tests are run and must pass.

Can you be a bit more specific about your problem?

It's quite possible to deploy code (all tests pass) and then to have tests failing two weeks later without having changed any code.
Reasons for this would include:

1. If your tests are working on production data (seealldata = true) then the particular records they pick up today aren't the same as the ones they used two weeks ago
2. Validation rules. If you add a validation rule, which can be done through the UI, this can cause a test to fail if for example it is inserting test data which fails the new criteria.

You can view some information about changes made to the environment by reviewing Setup | Security Controls | View Setup Audit Trail

You should be able to delete (destructive deploy) a class from Production as long as it is not referenced elsewhere. For example in a test class or a page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Doug. Yes, I know trigger or class code cannot be changed directly in Production. The changes I am attempting to track are the type you indicated such as val rules and such through the UI. And those are the type of changes I'm talking about. I would like to see a list of EVERY validation rule throughout the entire Production and their last modification date. I would like to do the same with fields. I will attempt to use the View Setup Audit Trail as you suggested. Thank you very much.

Comment: The view setup audit trail will let you download a CSV of all the changes made over the last six months, and if you know that the problem was introduced over the past two weeks you can focus on that period. If you are seeing a specific error message then that may also lead you to focus on a particular object or class.

Comment: Thank you very much Doug. I've never used that before and it's exactly what I needed !